# Contour integral of convergent power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, contour-integration

Given that $\frac{e^z}{z^k} = z^{-k} + z^{1-k} + \frac{z^{2-k}}{2!} + \frac{z^{3-k}}{3!} + ...$ converges uniformly on any set $\{z \in C: r \leq |z| \leq Z\}$ (where $0 < r < R$), show that for $k> 0$, $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z^k} dz = \frac{2\pi i}{(k-1)!}$.

What I've done thus far:

$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z^k} dz = \int_{\gamma} (z^{-k} + z^{1-k} + \frac{z^{2-k}}{2!} + \frac{z^{3-k}}{3!} + ...)dz = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \cdot \int_{\gamma} z^{(n-1)-k}$.  At this point I substitute $z = re^{i\theta}, dz = ire^{i\theta} d\theta$.  We have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \cdot \int_0^{2\pi} (re^{i\theta})^{(n-1)-k}\cdot ire^{i\theta} d\theta = \sum \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \cdot ir^{n-k} \cdot \int e^{i\theta (n-k)} d\theta$.  I'm stuck with what to do here and moreover I feel like the answer is heading in the wrong direction.  Tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path, you just need to realize that $$\int e^{i\theta(n-k)}d\theta= \cases{ 0~\text{if}~n \neq k\cr2\pi~\text{if}~n = k}$$

Comment: How do we have 1 if n= k?  I would have thought e^(0) = 1 implying the integral equals theta across 0 to 2pi, i.e the answer is 2pi, no?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, the integrand is 1, the result is $2\pi$. Edited to address.